# Why does my Workspaces stops? Eclipse che

Tags: java, eclipse, server, minecraft, eclipse-che

sorry for my English ...
currently i made a server for minecraft with Eclipse che and ngrok
and the server works correctly and I can play without problems, but in approximately 15 minutes the Eclipse page will go into "Offline" mode causing my server to shut down and I have to start it again, does anyone know what I have to do to avoid it?
Cheers!

Note* 
In my Workspaces I am only running two terminals,
one starting the server and the other the ngrok

commands used

sh start-server.sh

run this----
cd server && java -Xmx512M -Xms512M -jar server.jar nogui

sh start-ngrok.sh

run this---- ./ngrok authtoken "My authtoken "
./ngrok tcp 25565

Comment: Probably there is no activity neither in browser no in terminal.
The solution will be to disable activity checker.
But anyway it is better to ask a question here https://github.com/eclipse/che

Comment: Thank you! but i can't find where to disable idle time. :c

Comment: You can set `CHE_LIMITS_WORKSPACE_IDLE_TIMEOUT=-1` of che-server configuration to completely disable idling. See more https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-7/installation-guide/advanced-configuration-options-for-the-che-server-component/.